# What files are necessary for clang to function?

Tags: c++, windows, clang

I have built clang from source on windows using visual studio 2022. My configuration is `MinSizeRel` and my platform is `x64`. I am trying to cut down clang so it is functional but does not take up much storage.

Firstly, after building it, there are two folders, `bin`  and `lib`. Is the `lib` folder necessary? Can I remove it with no consequences?

Secondly, I am using clang for only C++ so are there any files I can remove from the `bin` folder? `clang-cl.exe` seems pretty useless for C++.

Comment: You should not remove anything from the installed build result. If you don't need some of the compiled tools, then you can disable them in the build configuration before you start building LLVM/Clang. The LLVM/Clang build system has a lot of CMake options for that. `lib` is absolutely necessary. `clang-cl.exe` is also useful for C++ (I don't know why you think it is C only).

Comment: `clang-cl` is useful for integrating Clang with VS, it imitates `cl` (MSVC), the VS's own compiler.

Comment: Why is this so important to you?  I stopped micro-managing disk space years ago.